# Go back to the Grid view and show the grid and the subgrid already open

Tags: grid, edit

I have this awkward request for the following implementation:
I have one view with a DataGrid and a SubGrid that appears inline everytime I press an ID on the main grid. On this subgrid, I have an action button that takes me into a new view and allows users to see and interact with the data related to that subgrid.

The request is that after editing some in this second view it should go back to the Grid view and show the grid and the subgrid already open. **Is there any other natural way of fulfilling this request?**

**They want users to see the previous grid and subgrid open as it was when the view was changed**

Sorry, I cant show screens to help visualize due the data displayed does not allow me to do it.

Comment: Without at least some visualization of what you're trying to do here, it's going to be very difficult to give a good answer. If privacy is a concern, use the built-in mockup tool to quickly produce a basic sketch of what you're dealing with, and use some placeholder data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when i press on the ID an AJAX call is made which fetches the data and then populates the sub-grid, you can display the edit screen in a pop-up window and then refresh the sub-grid data on save.

This way, since you are not navigating away from the home page you don't need to worry about coming back to the home page and restoring it to its previous state.

Comment: Seams a great solution. The reason why I'm changing views is that the detail view is a full page with an embed PDF using 50% of the space on the left and the details on the right but still is a valid solution.

Comment: Can we do the following :- 1. On Action Button Click, open the edit page in a new window. 2. Provide a small refresh button on the upper right corner of the subgrid table. On click of that button the sub grid will refresh the data.